# Getting Contents of Txt file into output

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to get a list of a specific adsite servers from all DC's.  I have the DC's saved as a txt file and I am running a foreach against it.  I would like to get the DC name from within the text file as part of the output.

So far I have

```
$servers = gc dclist.txt 

Foreach ($server in $servers){

Get-ADReplicationSite SomeCity -server $server  |select InterSiteTopologyGenerator 

}
```

And the output looks like:

```
CN=NTDS Settings,CN=DomainControllerX,CN=Servers,CN=SomeCity,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=com
CN=NTDS Settings,CN=DomainControllerX,CN=Servers,CN=SomeCity,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=com
CN=NTDS Settings,CN=DomainControllerX,CN=Servers,CN=SomeCity,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=com
CN=NTDS Settings,CN=DomainControllerX,CN=Servers,CN=SomeCity,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=com
```

How can I get the corresponding server at the front of this output, ideally something like:

```
DomainControllerA CN=NTDS Settings,CN=DomainControllerX,CN=Servers,CN=SomeCity,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=com

DomainControllerB CN=NTDS Settings,CN=DomainControllerX,CN=Servers,CN=SomeCity,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
... | select @{n='Server';e={$server}}, InterSiteTopologyGenerator
```

or

```
... | % {$server + ' ' + $_.InterSiteTopologyGenerator}
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony, works great.  What does the n= and e= stand for?